# Does restoring iPhone as a new phone overwrite iCloud backup?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I have a iCloud+ account with my iPhone with automatic savings. I had to restore my phone and decided to do restore from iCloud backup when setting up the phone. But it was very slow and i need my phone as i was about to travel and need my train ticket so i've restored it as a new iPhone and just logged to apple id account as requested.

At the train station, i decided to check to restore the iPhone from iCloud backup but i realised that the automatic savings was on and my backup went from 80 to 26 go. I quickly disabled everything in the iCloud menu, but the date of the iCloud backup is still the day before yesterday.

As i'm in the train now i cant do anything but did my old backup was overwritten partially with the new phone ? if its the case why the date shows day before yesterday ? because it didnt had the time to finish ?

I don't know what to do and im afraid to have lost a part of my backup, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All iCloud backups are overwritten (eventually).

The way it works is your phone will make a new backup every day until it runs out of space, then it will overwrite the *oldest* in it’s set  (you can have more than one phone backing up to a single iCloud account.

The easiest way to ensure that you have enough space for both of your phones’ backup sets is to purchase 50GB of storage for $0.99 per month (North American pricing).   See the [iCloud+ pricing page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201238) for additional regions.

#### Video

I found a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/_VNsH_OWmRw?si=mbimN5_N24dL3i3x&t=50) (produced by Apple Support) that depicts the available backups you can restore from (time index = 50 seconds; full video 1:43).

[image]

Comment: I have a 200go account so the 80go was the only backup there, so 120go of free space. does it mean my complete backup is still here even it says 26go ?

Comment: It does one complete, then incrementally each day.  Your complete should be there

Comment: but as it was the same device but restored as a new phone, did it erase the old one instead of increment it as there were not the files on the backup on the phone anymore ?

Comment: The old backups  are still there.

Comment: So i just have to restore from the backup even if it displays a wrong size and i'll have my phone restored as before ?

Comment: I just verified my most recent iPhone Backup (128GB model) and it was just 2.79GB.  My old iPhone 7 (32GB model) was treated as a new device after resetting (like yours) and the initial backup was only 8GB because nothing was installed/restored before backing up.

Comment: Old backup was indeed there and it worked, thanks ! I had to restore the iPhone again without doing any backup and restore from iCloud directly from the beginning. The screen 'restoring from iCloud' is only a few minutes contrary to what I thought. It gives you access to the phone just after and continues the restoring in the background.

Comment: Love to hear it!